# Get rid of cell widget in QTableWidgetItem

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtablewidget

As you may know, you can set a widget for a cell in a QTableWidget using `setCellWidget`:

```
table->setCellWidget(0, 0, new QProgressBar);
```

In some circumstances, I just want to get rid of this widget and everything becomes like when there was no cell widget. I tested setting widget to `nullptr` but It wasn't helpful.
In other words, What is the default widget of a cell in `QTableWidget`?

Comment: @eyllanesc I think there is not so much difference between setting it to zero or nullptr, nevertheless, That wasn't helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [`void QTableWidget::removeCellWidget(int row, int column)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#removeCellWidget)

In your case:

```
table->removeCellWidget(0, 0);
```

Comment: Qt Assistant does not mention `removeCellWidget` in see also of `setCellWidget` x_X, Thanks though man ;).

Comment: How strange in my Qt Assistant if it is.